# Removing Extra Space when CSS 'float' is used

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am unable to remove the extra space above 'Smart Filter' in the div id='container_sidebar', this example posted on fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/XHPtc/

Seems like if I remove the float: right property of that div 'container_sidebar' I will remove that extra space above but obviously that will destroy the layout. Any idea what may be the bug?

Comment: Which extra space you want to remove?

Comment: +1 on that question. I don't see the problem in your layout !

Comment: Where's the extra space? PrintScr and post-edit your question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `margin-bottom: 20px;` from `#searchresult_filter_box` CSS.

Answer (score 3):

problem is in searchresult_filter_box

you have bottom margin of 20 px there

To find out I used Inspect Element in Firebug, similar result you can see in Opera
(but the jsFiddle looks like a useful thing, I didn't know that one)